# Are $\mathbb{R}^1$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ the same infinity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've seen a proof that shows that rational numbers are not the same infinity as real numbers.

I'm curious if there is a proof that shows $\mathbb{R}^1$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the same infinity. If so, is there a way to map from one to the other for all points?

Comment: I apologize for the categorization. I took a stab at what I thought this might be related to. Its beyond what I learned in college.

Comment: I think this might be a repeat of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75107/injective-map-from-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr, can someone confirm?

Comment: Are you asking if they have the same cardinality?

Comment: Yes, and if you can map from one to the other. I think the link in my 2nd comment is asking the same thing and there is a solution, so I think the answer is yes.

Comment: @venomfangs About the link: yes. Since there exist well-known injective maps $\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$, the existence of an injective map $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ yields that there exists a bijection $\Bbb R^2\leftrightarrow \Bbb R$, via Cantor-Bernstein theorem.

Comment: If two sets have the same cardinality it means that there exists a bijection between them.

Comment: The two sets have the same cardinality.  The question you refer to can be used as a main step in the proof.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I need to confirm this before I posted the next part of my question, which is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765522/mathbbr2-to-mathbbr1-injective-mapping-while-preserving-metric-space