# $f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)\iff x_1=x_2\quad,\quad y_1=y_2$

Tags: functions

I came upon a question and I'm stuck on solving it.

> Does there exist any continuous function $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ such that $$f(x_1,y_1)=f(x_2,y_2)\iff x_1=x_2\quad,\quad y_1=y_2$$?
>
> What if we drop the continuity constraint? (though, the function is better be well-defined)

Originally, this question comes from a physical background. If two inertial frames measure the 4-tuples $(\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z,\Delta t)$ and $(\Delta x',\Delta y',\Delta z',\Delta t')$, we have $$\begin{cases}\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2-c^2\Delta t^2=\Delta x'^2+\Delta y'^2+\Delta z'^2-c^2\Delta t'^2
&,\quad\text{Special Relativity}\\
\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2=\Delta x'^2+\Delta y'^2+\Delta z'^2\\\text{and}
\\\Delta t=\Delta t'
&,\quad\text{Classical Physics}
\end{cases}$$
I am OK with special relativity, but about the the second equivalence, I wonder if a function $f$ is found such that $$f(\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2,c^2\Delta t^2)=f(\Delta x'^2+\Delta y'^2+\Delta z'^2,c^2\Delta t'^2)\\\iff \\
\Delta x^2+\Delta y^2+\Delta z^2=\Delta x'^2+\Delta y'^2+\Delta z'^2\\\text{and}
\\\Delta t=\Delta t'
$$

Comment: You are asking if there is a one-to-one function $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes. Another way of saying that.

Comment: see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197735/injective-function-from-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr

Comment: Oh. Thanks for that!

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75107/injective-map-from-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr

Answer (score 2):

For $f$ continuous, let $f(a,b)>f(c,d)>f(e,g)$.

Choose any path from $(a,b)$ to $(e,g)$ avoiding $(c,d)$. The image of this path is a path which must include all points between $f(a,b)$ to $f(e,g)$.

Thus there is another point with the same image as $(c,d)$.

> A neat (?) function $f$ if the continuity constraint is dropped.

For $x\in \Bbb R$ define $a(x)=\frac{e^x}{2e^x+1}$.

For $x\in \Bbb Q$ define $b(x)=0.5+\frac{x}{\sqrt 5}$. For $x\in \Bbb R- \Bbb Q$ define $b(x)=x$.

Using the continued fraction form for irrational numbers in $(0,1)$, define $c([0;x_1,x_2,...],[0;y_1,y_2,...])=[0;x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,...]$.

We can then define the function $f$ from $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ by 
$$f(x,y)=c(ba(x),ba(y)).$$

Comment: Note:  this makes use of continuity. If we drop continuity, it is possible.

Comment: Yes, is there a function with a neat/elementary definition?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Randall I've made a stab at something which looks reasonably neat.